# Nginx proxy pass not rendering

Tags: nginx, mediawiki, nginx-reverse-proxy, webmin

I'm trying to serve some services as a subdomain but it looks like nginx is not doing it right.
I have 3 docker containers serving zabbix, webmin and mediawiki.

- *example.com/zabbix* (works fine)
- *example.com/webmin* (not rendering)
- *example.com/wiki* (not rendering)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name             example.com;
    root                    /var/www/html/;
    

    location /zabbix {
        proxy_pass          http://192.168.0.71:8081;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /wiki {
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.0.71:8080;
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /webmin {
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.0.71:10000;
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Also add in */etc/webmin/config*:

```
webprefix=/webmin
webprefixnoredir=1
```

and *LocalSettings.php*

```
$wgServer = "http://example.com";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

wiki pages and webmin looks weird:
[wiki screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcVHN.png)

Any help will be appreciated
thanks!

Comment: I am surprised that *MediaWiki* works at all. As to the absence of styles, it seems that `index.php` is served but `load.php` is not. However, without the relevant nginx configuration from the container running MediaWiki little can be done to help you.

Comment: thanks you,
mediawiki is served by apache in its container... what file would you like to see?

Comment: Unfortunately, I havent' worked with Apache for many years. However, I recomment that you publish here all relevant config files, including `.htaccess`. Meanwhile, in browser Developer tools look all requests to `load.php` (there will be a few) and what is the response to them.